# Azure ML CLI v2 create data asset with MLTable

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, parquet, azure-machine-learning-service

I uploaded parquet files to a blobstorage and created a data asset via the Azure ML GUI. The steps are precise and clear and the outcome is as desired. For future usage I would like to use the CLI to create the data asset and new versions of it.

The base command would be `az ml create data -f <file-name>.yml`. The docs provide [a minimal example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-create-data-assets?tabs=cli#the-mltable-file) of a *MLTable* file which should reside next to the parquet files.

```
# directory in blobstorage
├── data
│   ├── MLTable
│   ├── file_1.parquet
.
.
.
│   ├── file_n.parquet
```

I am still not sure how to properly specify those files in order to create a tabular dataset with column conversion.

Do I need to specify the full path or the pattern in the `yml` file?

```yaml
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/data.schema.json

type: mltable
name: Test data
description: Basic example for parquet files
path: azureml://datastores/workspaceblobstore/paths/*/*.parquet # pattern or path to dir?
```

I have more confusion about the *MLTable* file:

```yaml
type: mltable

paths:
  - pattern: ./*.parquet
transformations:
  - read_parquet:
      # what comes here?
```

E.g. I have a column with dates with format `%Y-%m%d %H:%M:%S` which should be converted to a timestamp. (I can provide this information at least in the GUI!)

Any help on this topic or hidden links to documentation would be great.

Comment: Including the base repository location, need to give the complete path of **YML** file.

Comment: @TadepalliSairam you mean the complete path when using `az ml data create -f`? That's true but what about the content of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working MLTable file to convert string columns from parquet files looks like this:

```yaml
--- 
type: mltable
paths: 
  - pattern: ./*.parquet
transformations: 
  - read_parquet: 
      include_path_column: false
  - convert_column_types:
      - columns: column_a
        column_type:
          datetime:
            formats:
              - "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
  - convert_column_types:
    - columns: column_b
      column_type:
        datetime:
          formats:
            - "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

(By the way, at the moment of writing this specifying multiple columns as array did not work, e.g. `columns: [column_a, column_b]`)

Answer (score -2):

To perform this operation, we need to check with installations and requirements for the experiment. We need to have valid subscription and workspace.

Install the required mltable library.

There are 4 different supported paths as the parameters in Azure ML

•   Local computer path

•   Path on public server like HTTP/HTTPS

•   Path on azure storage (Like blob in this case)

•   Path on datastore

Create a YAML file in the folder which was created as an assert
Filename can be anything (filename.yml)

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/data.schema.json
type: uri_folder
name: <name_of_data>
description: <description goes here>
path: <path>
to create the data assert using CLI. 
az ml data create -f filename.yml
```

To create a specific file as the data asset

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/data.schema.json
# Supported paths include:
# local: ./<path>/<file>
# blob:  https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<path>/<file>
# ADLS gen2: abfss://<file_system>@<account_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path>/<file>
# Datastore: azureml://datastores/<data_store_name>/paths/<path>/<file>
type: uri_file
name: <name>
description: <description>
path: <uri>
```

All the paths need to be mentioned according to your workspace credentials.

To create MLTable file as the data asset.

Create a yml file with the data pattern like below with the data in your case

```
type: mltable
paths:
  - pattern: ./*.filetypeextension
transformations:
  - read_delimited:
      delimiter: ,
      encoding: ascii
      header: all_files_same_headers
```

Use the below python code to use the MLTable

```
import mltable
table1 = mltable.load(uri="./data")
df = table1.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

To create MLTable data asset. Use the below code block.

```
$schema: https://azuremlschemas.azureedge.net/latest/data.schema.json
# path must point to **folder** containing MLTable artifact (MLTable file + data
# Supported paths include:
# blob:  https://<account_name>.blob.core.windows.net/<container_name>/<path>
type: mltable
name: <name_of_data>
description: <description goes here>
path: <path>
```

Blob is the storage mechanism in the current requirement.

The same procedure is used to create a data asset of MLTable

```
az ml data create -f <file-name>.yml
```

Comment: thank you for you answer but unfortunately it does not match my question. The input data at hand are parquet files not csv files. In addition I cannot see any hint on how to specify the column transformation of a date column in yaml. The answer more or less covers the excisting official Microsoft documentation but does not go further. :-(

Comment: let me add the additional requirements into the answer.